# Is it possible to trigger a run configuration to execute after a make in Intellij

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, run-configuration

The maven integration in Intellij has a nice feature to trigger a maven lifecycle phase before/after a make/rebuild. Is there any way I can do this with a run configuration?

Comment: You can have a launch configuration run another launch configuration *before* it runs, does that help?

Comment: No, I'm looking to attach it to the 'make' or 'rebuild' so that I don't have to do the make, and then do the run configuration when the make is done

Comment: I don't quite get what you're trying to accomplish. Why don't you run the configuration and attach the make to it? Why do you have to use make as a trigger?

Comment: Make is a much more available command with a hot-key, it's own dedicated button, etc. I have multiple run configurations and I want to only make one click of the mouse instead of 3 (switch run config and press start).